# Boto SQS: delete RawMessage

Tags: python, boto, amazon-sqs

I am using python boto 2.8 and i couldn't delete the messages. Here is my test code:

```
conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("us-east-1",
                                  aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                                  aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY)

q = conn.get_queue("sqs_bounces")
q.set_message_class(RawMessage) //need this to be able to get message as json
results = q.get_messages(num_messages=10,visibility_timeout=30,wait_time_seconds=10)
for rs in results:
    str = rs.get_body()
    print str
    result = json.loads(str)
    rs = json.loads(result["Message"])
    print rs["notificationType"]
    #get the email and save it as bounced
    // Do saving.....

    #Delete message
    //How do i delete the current message?
```

Could anyone here guide me how to delete this? Sometimes i get 1 message, sometimes 3. And i don't want to save the same bounce email each pull, that's why i need to delete it once i save them.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of the objects in the returned result set is a RawMessage object which has a `delete` method.  So, if you coded your loop a bit more like this:

```
for msg in results:
    body = msg.get_body()
    body = json.loads(body)
    message_body = json.loads(body['Message'])
    ...
    msg.delete()
```

You should be able to delete the message.

Comment: Thnx mate! It worked. I saw that method but it didn't have any description.